# AWS Amplify Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() not pulling custom attributes from Cognito User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm working with an AWS Amplify project, specifically using the Amplify Auth module in a React application for authentication. I have set up a Cognito User Pool with custom attributes and users are successfully created and authenticated.

The problem I'm encountering is when I call Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() from the Amplify library to fetch the currently authenticated user's data, it doesn't return the custom attributes I set up in Cognito.

Here is the function where I'm calling Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser():

```
async function checkUser() {
    try {
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      const userGroup = user.attributes["custom:group"];
      console.log("USER GROUP", userGroup)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

This function successfully logs the user data to the console, but `user.attributes["custom:group"]` is undefined, even though I have confirmed that the `custom:group` attribute exists and is set for the user in the Cognito User Pool.

Here is how I am invoking the `checkUser` function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    checkUser();
  }, []);
```

I have also tried introducing a delay before calling checkUser():

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => checkUser(), 5000);
  }, []);
```

...but `user.attributes["custom:group"]` still logs as undefined.

I have confirmed that my AWS Amplify project has the necessary permissions to use `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`. The `.catch()` block in `checkUser()` does not log any errors, so it appears that the call to `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` is successful.

Is there something I'm missing in the configuration that's causing the custom attributes not to be fetched? I'd appreciate any advice or suggestions on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Auth.userAttributes`.
Example,

```js
async () => {
  const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  const attributes = await Auth.userAttributes(user);
  console.log(`attributes:`, attributes);
```

This should include custom attributes, which can be accessed as follows,

```js
attributes.find(attribute => attribute.Name === 'custom:group')?.Value
```

Another point to remember is that, invoking `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser` fetches the user from cache (e.g. localStorage) by default and doesn't perform any API request.

If you wanna fetch the [latest state of the user](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#retrieve-current-authenticated-user), invoke `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser` as follows

```js
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
  bypassCache: true // Optional, By default is false. If set to true, this call will send a request to Cognito to get the latest user data
})
```